# SQL - Assign row numbers based on whether other rows in the result have a column value same as the current row, if yes assign same row number to them

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to assign row number/ rank dynamically to record while selecting, so that all the items from a particular `HOTEL` is allotted same row number if `Meal` is included in any of it's `TYPE`, else all will have cumulative/ subsequent row value/ rank from the previous one. Here's how my table looks

[image: Table]

and this is how it needs to be with the row numbers

[image: Final Table].

I tried using ROW_NUMBER() and DENSE_RANK() over `HOTEL` but they seem to be assigning same row number for records having same `HOTEL` but not having `Meal` included in it's `TYPE`.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms